# How can I comment an HTML tag attribute in HTML source code?

Tags: html

**For example:**

```
<a /*title="need to be comment out"*/>a link</a>
```

Comment: Is there a reason you only want to comment them out? Do you need them to exist afterwards? If not you could completely remove them.

Comment: @Pit Just like coding other languages. sometimes, I need to comment it out for testing.

Comment: On mac (using the program ; Coda) you can simply press CMD + / 
after selecting the items ofcourse

Comment: A workaround is to have a script (or similar) strip out (remove) such comments before other parts of the system sees it. I did it for [WiX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WiX) source code (pure XML) to able to use comments inside tags. The script was the first to be called by the build process. Per-line comments (`//`) were also enabled by this.

Comment: Related (using `<!`): *[Does HTML5 change the standard for HTML commenting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29405858/)*

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The [W3C documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.2.4) suggests it cannot be done:

> Note that comments are markup.

This basically means that a `<!-- ...>` comment tag is just like any other tag, so `<a <!--title="need to be comment out"-->>a link</a>` is as wrong as `<a <span></span>>a link</a>`.

For quick hacking I believe a common option is to rename that attribute. While you obtain invalid HTML, you can temporarily remove the attribute:

```
<a xtitle="need to be comment out">a link</a>
```

If you happen to be using a server-side language, you can also use its own comment syntax. For instance, in PHP you can do this:

```
<a <?php/*title="need to be comment out"*/?>>a link</a>
```

... which generates this HTML:

```
<a >a link</a>
```

... and in [ASP.NET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET) you can use `<%-- Comment goes here --%>` while the [ASP.NET MVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET_MVC) [Razor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET_Razor) syntax is `@* Comment goes here *@`.

Comment: You might want to make it more obvious you have purposely "commented" the attribute out. For instance with comment_out_title="...". It may be assumed to be a mispelling.

Comment: You do not obtain invalid HTML if you use `data-` attributes, for example, `<a data-xtitle="need to be comment out">a link</a>`, though many best practices, including those by such big frameworks as Angular, disadvise this.

Comment: A minor thing, but in PHP, you can remove the space, as well, with, for example, `<a<? php /* title="need to be comment out"*/ ?>>a link</a>`.

Answer (score 7):

You can't. Comments can only start and end outside tags.

Some people preprend an x to an attribute name, thus changing it and causing it to be all but ignored (since it is still often visible in the DOM), but this is invalid.

Comment: Yes, this is super-easy, I also do this to "comment" bits of CSS.  I call it "spoiling" the line.

Answer (score 7):

I usually just put `_x` at the end of the attribute name. Then the attribute is ignored because it's unknown. So if I wanted to comment out the `id` attribute from this element:

```
<input type="text" name="name" id="name">
```

I would change it to this:

```
<input type="text" name="name" id_x="name">
```

This also has the advantage of being able to search for "`_x=`" to find all commented attributes.

Comment: Obviously this trick should only be used when developing and "commented" attributes shouldn't be left in production code.

Comment: nice, i use just `-id="name"`

Comment: @ChrisNash In general, commented out HTML shouldn't be left in code.

Answer (score 2):

This cannot be done, but an attribute can be removed via the `removeAttribute(attribute_name)` JavaScript call.

Alternatively, you can prefix the attributes you want removed with a namespace like `<a nosuchns:title="nevershown">click</a>` and remove the namespace via JavaScript.