# XML Comment Inside Element

Tags: xml

In the following XML, what is the alternative way to place a comment over the attributes of element?

```
  <!-- I can comment here -->

  <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView_ben"

        <!-- Cannot place a comment here  -->

        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26461869/how-to-comment-attributes-inside-xml-tag

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No, this isn't possible. Comments are not allowed in an XML open tag.

See [How do I comment attributes inside an XML tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26461869/how-to-comment-attributes-inside-xml-tag)

Answer (score 1):

A comment can only appear before or after the start tag (regardless of whether it is an empty tag).

A comment may **not** appear within the **[start-tag](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#dt-stag)** of an XML element:

> `[40] STag ::= '<' Name (S Attribute)* S? '>'`

Nor may a comment appear within an end-tag:

> `[44] EmptyElemTag ::= '<' Name (S Attribute)* S? '/>'`

In general, per section [**2.5 Comments**](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-comments):

> [Definition: **Comments** may appear anywhere in a document outside
>   other [markup](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#dt-markup); in addition, they may appear within the document
>   type declaration at places allowed by the grammar. ...]

---

Here is one way to document element attributes:

```
  <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView_ben"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
  <!--  
        android:id="@+id/textView_ben"
            addresses defect #123
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            blah blah blah -->
```

Alternatively, such a comment may appear *before* the tag; it just cannot appear *within* a tag.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed there are no "real" comments (ignored by the parser). But like in Python, where doc strings are commonly used for comments, you might simply use your own attributes as comments (and ignore them by yourself):

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView_ben"             comment1="this id is used for ..."
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"     comment2="keep in mind, that ..."
/>
```