# Comment out a single directive or property in Angular html template

Tags: html, angular, comments, angular-template

Is there a way to comment out lines with `*ngIf`, `(opened)`, `[expanded]` in this example?

```
    <mat-expansion-panel
         *ngIf="block"
         (opened)="panelOpened.emit()"
         [expanded]=expanded
    >
```

I have read [How to comment HTML tag attribute in HTML source code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4744353/how-to-comment-html-tag-attribute-in-html-source-code) before posting my question. There is a solution for plain html attributes, but it's not working in Angular.

Comment: Rename the attributes to `data-ngIf`, `data-opened` and `data-expanded` and should Angula ignore them.

Comment: I usually move them out of the html tag and comment them

Comment: @Reactgular Thanks for your idea. It works even with brackets: `data-[expanded]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like adding `data-` is the simplest solution. Thanks [@Reactgular](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1031569/reactgular) for this idea:

```
<mat-expansion-panel
         data-ngIf="block"
         data-(opened)="panelOpened.emit()"
         data-[expanded]=expanded
    >
```